# Nodejs - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I have the following

SessionController.js

```js
import User from '../models/User';

class SessionController {
   async store(req, res) {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      console.log(req.body);

      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
   }
}

export default new SessionController();
```

User.js

```js
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

class User extends Model {
   static init(sequelize) {
      super.init(
         {
            name: Sequelize.STRING,
            email: Sequelize.STRING,
            password_hash: Sequelize.STRING,
         },
         {
            sequelize,
         }
      );

      return this;
   }

   checkPassword(password) {
      return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password_hash);
   }
}

export default User;
```

And Insomnia to send data from /sessions route
[image]

I call `console.log(req.body)` and I get all data, so I don't know why I'm getting this error:

```
(node:8589) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Function.findAll (/home/julio/www/bootcamp2019/gympoint/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1692:47)
    at Function.findOne (/home/julio/www/bootcamp2019/gympoint/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1924:17)
    at store (/home/julio/www/bootcamp2019/gympoint/src/app/controllers/SessionController.js:10:41)......
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

The same problem was happening to me.

I was able to find out that I had the wrong database path you can see on lines 4 and 5.

```js
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes';

// import './config/database'; (Wrong)
import './database'; // (Correct)

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.server = express();

    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.server.use(express.json());
  }

  routes() {
    this.server.use(routes);
  }
}

export default new App().server;
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your await call of async function in try/catch block.

```
import User from '../models/User';

class SessionController {
    async store(req, res) {
        try {
            const { email, password } = req.body;

            console.log(req.body);

            const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error Occurred", e)
        }

    }
}

export default new SessionController();
```